# AWS ECS container restart error: InvalidIdInRequest: CredentialsV2Request: Credentials not found

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

Hi I'm facing issue while i try to restart a container running in the AWS ECS EC2instance. the below is the error response:

```
$ docker restart e93f2ea71c66
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container e93f2ea71c66: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: CredentialsEndpointError: failed to load credentials
caused by: InvalidIdInRequest: CredentialsV2Request: Credentials not found
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the agent log (/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log)?

Comment: Are these EC2 instances using Amazon provided ECS optimized AMIs or your custom built AMIs ? Do you have a task execution role attached ?

Comment: yeah i have attached the task execution role.

Comment: I'm running in the same issue suddenly. Before the last deploy all did working well. But not now. How did yo solve it?